# add a new field/attribute to many bibtex entries

Tags: bibtex, doi, bibentry

I have a (big) bibtex database like I show below. I need to add the DOI field to every entry. This new field is just a copy of URLDOI, but without URL and "http://dx.doi.org/" (see the second piece of code) . Is there any way (= tool, code, etc) to do automatically (or something similar)?   Thanks!

Original database of entries:

```
@article{xxxAl:2016,
  author = {authors},
  title = {title},
  journal = {journal},
  year = 2016,
  pages = {19:1--19:69},
  publisher = oxford,
  urldoi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S2956796816000162},
  volume = 26,
  month = sep,
}

@inproceedings{2016,
  author = {authors2},
  title = {title2},
  pages = {298--310},
  urldoi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2951913.2951933},
}
```

change to:

```
@article{xxxAl:2016,
  author = {authors},
  title = {title},
  journal = {journal},
  year = 2016,
  pages = {19:1--19:69},
  publisher = oxford,
  urldoi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S2956796816000162},
  doi = {10.1017/S2956796816000162},
  volume = 26,
  month = sep,
}

@inproceedings{2016,
  author = {authors2},
  title = {title2},
  pages = {298--310},
  urldoi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2951913.2951963},
  doi = {10.1145/2951913.2951963},
}
```

Comment: This is not really a latex question and can, instead, be done with any  editor that accepts regular expressions. For example, you could do this with [vim](https://www.vim.org/) using `:%s/urldoi = {http:\/\/dx.doi.org\/\([^}]*\)}\,$/&^M  doi = {\1},/`. (Any existing `doi` entries would be doubled.)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, I am looking for this kind of solution! I used the solution with VimR (for MacOSX). I only have issue with the solution. Is it possible to replace `^M` with a break line ("intro" key)? Because when I now apply the solution I get  `urldoi ={http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cl.2003.09.002},^M doi = {10.1016/j.cl.2003.09.002},`. Thanks!

Comment: I just replaced `^M` with `\r`, thanks!

Comment: The `^M` is a new line character. You need to input it as `<cmd>-V<return>` - or use `\r`:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of @Andrew, I give a solution. Using an editor like Vim (in my case VimR), I use the following command:

```
:%s/urldoi = {http:\/\/dx.doi.org\/\([^}]*\)}\,$/&\r doi = {\1},/
```